# Jquery - Pass re-assigned Global variable to function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

So i have been working on this 'public chat' system for a while... I've succeeded with appending submitted message into the text box. But when it came to 'RECEIVING' other peoples messages, I failed.

The problem: I'm not able to use the re-assigned global variable inside a function.
I've assigned the global variable "global_msg_id" to an empty value in order to be able to re-assign it later inside ajax.

I want to pass the re-assigned variable (from ajax) to the function "message_receiver()"

```
var global_msg_id = "";

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#txtarea_msgsender").keydown(function(e){
        if(e.keyCode == 13 && !e.shiftKey) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var url = "/pages/pmsg_sr.php";

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: url,
                data: $("#msgbox_form").serialize(),
                dataType: "json",
                success: function(data) {
                    global_msg_id = data['id'];
                    $('#rec_sen').append('<div class="new_msg_box"><div class="new_msg_holder"><b>'+data['user']+': </b>'+data['message'].replace(/\\/g, '')+'</div></div>');
                    $('#txtarea_msgsender').val("");
                    $("#rec_sen").scrollTop($("#rec_sen")[0].scrollHeight - $("#rec_sen").height());
                }
            });
        }
    });

    /* ############ Message receiver ############## */
    setInterval(receive_message, 10000)

    function receive_message() {
        alert(global_msg_id); // RETURNS empty value
    }
});
```

Comment: Why are you using a global variable at all? Just make it a variable inside the document ready function...

Comment: How will that work m8

Comment: All your functions are inside the document ready function right? Then they should then have access to that variable.

Comment: @evolutionxbox - Using a variable inside document ready function was a good idea :)

Comment: Good. I hope that help (although it won't have answered your question)

Comment: You global message ID is being set inside the success callback of your jQuery post function. Is the success callback definitely being triggered? And, as it's asynchronous, is it being triggered before your 1 second delay expires that would run your receive_message function?

Comment: put `alert(global_msg_id);` inside the "success" function of the ajax call. You can't assume it will only take one second, it could be any length of time. The only reliable way to show the value is to wait for the ajax call to finish.